# How to add SomeLibrary.dll.config to project in VS2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, dll

Today I learned that one of the .NET libraries I use, OpenTK, [requires me to put OpenTK.dll.config in the dir of the app executable](http://www.opentk.com/node/2288). The question is, how do I do that conveniently in VS2008?

I can add it to my VS project next to my source files, and set it to "Copy if newer" - that works fine. But then my file list in the Solution Explorer is cluttered with this nonsource file in the middle of the source files. Any other way?

Comment: Stefan, if you think the answer has solved your issue, could you please close it?

Comment: @LeftyX: well, it hasn't really solved the issue. You're doing the same thing as I: putting the config file in the root, next to the source files. So, as I said in the question, then my file list in the Solution Explorer is cluttered with a nonsource file. You also mentioned putting the file in the bin folder directly. But I don't check my bin folder into SVN. I reserve the bin folder for things VS placed there on the "build" step. That way, I manage all my files from within the VS project.

Comment: @LeftyX: I *could* checkin a bin folder containing just the config file, but that doesn't seem clean. Hmm, on second thought this is technically a valid solution so I'll accept your answer. What I was hoping for was a way to "attach" the config file to the corresponding DLL in the "References" list, so VS knows that the dll needs the dll.config. Alternatively, I'd like to put the dll.config in a subfolder of the VS project, so it doesn't sit in the midst of the source files. But when it's in a folder, it doesn't get found when the exe launches.

Comment: You can only add references to dll.There are other work-around.You can put all your config files in a separate folder (ConfigFiles) and move them in the bin during compile. You can use this pre-build event > copy "$(ProjectDir)\ConfigFiles\Nhibernate.config" "$(TargetDir)"

Comment: @LeftyX: Great, thanks. I hadn't thought of using pre-build events for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I do.
I put the config file in the root and set "Copy Always" (Copy if newer is fine). Another alternative is to put it in your bin folder, maybe setting read-only attribute so you avoid to delete it by mistake. I tend to prefer the first solution cause:

A) I now I am using an external config file
B) I can update it easily from VS